# Rails js script code not working while screen back due to Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

In my rails app there is a JS script in partial view

```
 const f2s = window.document.createElement("script");
   f2s.defer = true;
   (f2s.src = "https://face2.oktium.com/face2widget.js"),
   (f2s.onload = function () {
   new window.Oktium(face2params).init();
   new window.Oktium(face2paramsMobile).init();
 }),
 document.head.appendChild(f2s);
```

it works fine when page load for first but when comes again from back or another page which have same code its not working. How can I work that with turbolinks?

Comment: Did you use turbolinks event handler?

Comment: no its just under script tag

Answer (score 3):

[From turbolinks docs](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements)

> ###### Working with Script Elements
>
> Your browser automatically loads and evaluates any `<script>` elements present on the initial page load.
>
> When you navigate to a new page, Turbolinks looks for any `<script>` elements in the new page’s `<head>` which aren’t present on the current page. Then it appends them to the current `<head>` where they’re loaded and evaluated by the browser. You can use this to load additional JavaScript files on-demand.
>
> Turbolinks evaluates `<script>` elements in a page’s `<body>` each time it renders the page. You can use inline body scripts to set up per-page JavaScript state or bootstrap client-side models. To install behavior, or to perform more complex operations when the page changes, avoid script elements and use the `turbolinks:load` event instead.
>
> Annotate `<script>` elements with `data-turbolinks-eval="false"` if you do not want Turbolinks to evaluate them after rendering. Note that this annotation will not prevent your browser from evaluating scripts on the initial page load.
>
> ###### Loading Your Application’s JavaScript Bundle
>
> Always make sure to load your application’s JavaScript bundle using `<script>` elements in the `<head>` of your document. Otherwise, Turbolinks will reload the bundle with every page change.
>
> ```html
> <head>
>   ...
>   <script src="/application-cbd3cd4.js" defer></script>
> </head>
> ```
>
> If you have traditionally placed application scripts at the end of `<body>` for performance reasons, consider using the [`<script defer>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attribute instead. It has [widespread browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer) and allows you to keep your scripts in `<head>` for Turbolinks compatibility.
>
> You should also consider configuring your asset packaging system to fingerprint each script so it has a new URL when its contents change. Then you can use the `data-turbolinks-track` attribute to force a full page reload when you deploy a new JavaScript bundle.

You can wrap your JS script inside such handler inside `script` tag in the `head`

```
<script defer>
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    // your code here
  })
</script>
```

Also in Rails there is mechanism how to add some tags dynamically, you can add in the `<head>` in `layout/application`

```
<%= yield(:face2) %>
```

And then in your specific view

```
<% content_for(:face2) do %>
  <script defer src="https://face2.oktium.com/face2widget.js" data-turbolinks-eval="false"></script>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
      new window.Oktium(face2params).init()
      new window.Oktium(face2paramsMobile).init()
    })
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @mechnocov thank you for your reply. I done this but code starts duplicating every time comes back

Comment: no how can I do that?

Comment: need to remove this one document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load') ??

Comment: I've updated answer, please try

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your JS code inside

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a repetition of what others have suggested, but I just wanted to stress that it was the wrapping of the functionality needed for the partial/view including variable declarations that worked for me. Initially I used the following in the erb which worked with some exceptions.

```
<div id="cart-counter" data-turbo-permanent>1 item</div>
```

This kind of worked but when user clicked button type submit on other pages, it broke again.

Tried many things, and as others have described, the following worked:
wrapped the script I needed for that view with :

```
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", ()=>{
  // functionality 
}
```